# Whats function f is doing?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor, constructor-overloading

Below is the code that I'm trying to figure out.  What is the function actually doing, right after I invoke the call the following constructors or the function?

My query is why i'm getting this kind of output, more specifically why "copy constructor called" gets printed 2 times. Please explain whats going in the background of this piece of code.

```cpp
 class a {

    public:
        a() //default constructor
        {
            cout<<endl<<"default constructor called";
        }
        a(const a &o)// parameterized constructor
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Copy constructor called";
        }
        a f(a o)// function of some kind i'm not getting
        {
            return o;
        }
}
```

Constructors and functions called:

```cpp
a (o1);

a o2(o1);

o1.f(o2); // correction : o2 as parameter in place of o1
```

Output :

> default constructor called
>
> copy constructor called
>
> copy constructor called
>
> copy constructor called

Comment: Are you asking why you get this output? Or something else? Please specify.

Comment: The function `f` takes an object by value and hence copies `o1` when it takes it. Depending on whether your compiler does [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (mandatory since C++17, very widespread before.)  or not, it copies the local object `o` on return. Therefore you get between 1 and 2 copy constructor calls for this function. (I thinkw with high optimization, your compiler could even optimize the whole function call away and you get 0 copies, but I am not sure.)

Comment: Passing `o1` by value to `o1.f()` passes a copy i.e. calls the copy constructor.  The `return o` inside the function returns a copy of the `o` to the caller  i.e. a second call of the copy constructor.   That's the base logic of your code, as shown.     In some circumstances, the compiler can elide one or more of those copies (i.e. not create them) but that is not (always) required, and evidently not happening in your case.

Comment: @Peter this explanation is letting me make some sense about the code ...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe f takes in a object of type a and then returns it, it does nothing to the object and is just a waste of time.

The other two functions don't do anything except output those strings.

o1.f(o1) just returns o1 and does not actually do anything in the code since that value is never used.

Comment: friend i think you are missing out the copy constructor.